# Navigator a partir de una clase + ListView en Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

tengo una clase que contiene diferentes propiedades, como el nombre de una categoria, imagen de fondo para su container, y un tercer campo que contiene la ruta a la que debe ir cada elemento generado en el listview una vez que hago clic en el.

Hasta ahora solo he trabajado con rutas fijas, como por ejemplo:

```
onTap: () {Navigator.push(
     context,
     MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) =>Details(),
```

sin embargo, ahora debo recorrer esa lista y que la ruta se actualice en cada elemento creado.
no consigo dar con la sintaxis correcta.

debo acceder a mi clase, que seria _griditems[index].route, sin embargo esto no obtiene resultados cuando lo plasmo en el navigator.push

debo obtener los datos de la siguiente clase:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   List<GridItems> _gridItems = [
    GridItems("Love", "Love.jpg", "Love") //el ultimo campo es la ruta a la que debo mandar al usuario con un clic,
    
  ];

class GridItems {
  String categoria, urlimg, route;

  GridItems(this.categoria, this.urlimg, this.route);
}
```

Comment: Pero "Love" es un String, ¿no? Y el builder recibe un widget, es imposible que funcione de esa forma, a no ser qué me esté perdiendo algo. En todo caso, si lo que quieres usar es un String como ruta, deberás usar Navigator.pushNamed() o que el tercer parámetro en lugar de ser un String sea un Widget, siendo este widget la página a donde quieres navegar.

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por tu respuesta, actualmente soy novato en Flutter, voy a investigar la forma de hacerlo utilizando Navigator.pushNamed(), como comentas, si, ahora mismo recibe un String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes la Clase:

```
class GridItems {
  String categoria, urlimg, route;
  GridItems(this.categoria, this.urlimg, this.route);
}
```

Tienes la Lista:

```
List<GridItems> gridItems = [
    GridItems("category 1", "urlimg 2", "/route1")
    GridItems("category 1", "urlimg 2", "/route2")
];
```

Con ListView lo puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
ListView.builder(
            itemCount: gridItems.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
              return ListTile(
                title: gridItems[i].categoria,
                subtitle: gridItems[i].urlimg,
                trailing: const Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, gridItems[i].route);
                },
              );
            }),
```

Por cada ítem seleccionado en la lista, puedes navegar hacia otra ruta. Puedes reemplazar el ListTile por cualquier otro widget que desees. Si creas tus propios widgets, te recomiendo utilizar la clase **GestureDetector**, con el atributo **onTap** simulas lo mismo.

De manera similar puedes aplicarlo en GridView.